# mapping Futura font in quartz for use in ggplot

Tags: r, fonts, quartz-graphics

I would like Futura to be the default font for my ggplot graphs. I'm running MacOSX, writing out to pngs, so it appears the "extrafont" is not applicable.

I've attempted mapping via quartzFont within the R environment with

```
> quartzFonts(sans = quartzFont(rep("Futura", 4)))
```

which appears to work because when I look at font mappings we have:

```
> quartzFonts()
$serif
[1] "Times-Roman"      "Times-Bold"       "Times-Italic"     "Times-BoldItalic"

$sans
[1] "Futura" "Futura" "Futura" "Futura"

$mono
[1] "Courier"             "Courier-Bold"        "Courier-Oblique"    
[4] "Courier-BoldOblique"
```

I've also set

```
> quartz.options(family="Futura")
```

But ggplot is still producing Helvetica titles and labels. What am I missing?

Comment: `theme(text=element_text(family="Futura")`

Comment: Error in grid.Call(L_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
    polygon edge not found
    In addition: Warning messages:
    In grid.Call(L_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
    no font could be found for family "Futura"

Comment: Give the `extrafont()`,  `font_import()` and `loadfonts()` dance a try. I had Futura LT on another system and tried to make it work on my primary R system w/o doing that dance and it didn't (same error you got). I also ended up having to refer to it as `FuturaLT` (no space) seeing how it was logged in `fonttable()`

Comment: I had a similar error caused by misspelling the font name, in my case ``family="helvetica"`` had to be ``family="Helvetica"``...