# ggplot can't change font face for text

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts

I'm creating a chart and want to change the font for the title and subtitle.

I would like the title to be Futura bold and the subtitle to be Futura plain.

```
# Get the mtcars dataset to create some example plots
data(mtcars)
df <- mtcars[, c("mpg", "cyl", "wt")]
# Convert cyl to a factor variable
df$cyl <- as.factor(df$cyl)
# Plot
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + 
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle('Basic Scatter Chart', subtitle = 'New ggplot theme') +
  theme(
    # Set title 
    plot.title = ggplot2::element_text(family='Futura',
                                       size=20,
                                       face='bold',
                                       color="#222222"),
    plot.subtitle = ggplot2::element_text(family= 'Futura',
                                          face='plain',
                                          size=16,
                                          margin=ggplot2::margin(9,0,9,0)))
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Error in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
  polygon edge not found
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  no font could be found for family "Futura"
2: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  no font could be found for family "Futura"
```

If I change the face argument from plain to bold, then the plot works, so it seems as though R can't find the plain variant of the Futura font. When I look in font book, I can see medium, medium italic, bold.

For other fonts that work with the face plain (e.g. Helvetica), they have a regular variant in font book.

How to I rectify this issue to get a plain variant of Futura to work? Can I not just assign medium to plain in R?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you do not have the futura font installed. Probably you have to install it first and import it to R.

Also have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32766040/mapping-futura-font-in-quartz-for-use-in-ggplot)